# Android calculate ListView Items

Tags: java, android, listview, r.java-file

Lately I have been working on my Shopping App. It's used commercially in the AppStore.
So a few of users asked for a function to directly add an article price and finally a total price of all list items. So I tried to realise this in my app.

So I have build my listview

```
items = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, R.id.txt, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And my listview works super. Now I want to get the position of an item in the ListView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            String value = (String)adapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

So and now I want to add a function to override my listview item and set a new 'Price'.

And last but not least my question. How can i get a total of all prices in the ListView?

> I mean 
>   (Position 1 1,99),
>   (Position 2 1,05),
>   (Position 3 4,50),
>   (Total      7,54),

Thx for all of your help :D

Comment: are you using custom adapter? if no, u need to use custom adapter to achieve your requirement.  example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `items = new ArrayList<String>();`, you should have a class Item with item's name and price

Comment: Ok. Thx for your help.

Comment: I have filter my listview position with an alphabetic and decimal filter. Put all Decimal together and give the result in a separat string on the xml out.

Comment: you mean that you use some sort of `Pattern` to take apart the name and the price ?

Comment: Yes :) I add a pattern ;)